# Error: A method is already defined?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, methods

I get the following error in my terminal when trying to build using the `meteor` command:

```
W20150920-14:33:43.538(-5)? (STDERR)          
W20150920-14:33:43.539(-5)? (STDERR) /Users/cwahlfeldt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.g96qzu++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150920-14:33:43.539(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150920-14:33:43.539(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150920-14:33:43.575(-5)? (STDERR) Error: A method named 'queuerInsert' is already defined
W20150920-14:33:43.575(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461:1
W20150920-14:33:43.575(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20150920-14:33:43.575(-5)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1459:1)
W20150920-14:33:43.575(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/collections/queuers.js:31:12
W20150920-14:33:43.575(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/collections/queuers.js:83:3
W20150920-14:33:43.576(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/queue/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150920-14:33:43.576(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150920-14:33:43.576(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/cwahlfeldt/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.g96qzu++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150920-14:33:43.576(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/queue/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
```

I haven't touched the local version of the app for a couple weeks and as far as I know the app was working fine then and so was its live, production counterpart. Ive reset the database using `meteor reset`, I also deleted the `.meteor/local/db/` directory and tried starting fresh with a new database.... still nothing. I have a working version up on Heroku and cloned that down and everything is working but I would like my original repo to work.

Thanks!

p.s. heres where the collection and methods are defined.

```
Queuers = new Mongo.Collection('queuers');

if (Meteor.server) {
    Meteor.methods({
        // insert a new queuer at the bottom of the list
        queuerInsert: function(queuerAttr) {
            var queuer = {
                name: queuerAttr.name,
                partySize: queuerAttr.partySize,
                phoneNumber: queuerAttr.phoneNumber,
                texted: false,
                date: new Date()
            };

            var queuerId = Queuers.insert(queuer);

            return {
                _id: queuerId
            };
        },
        // remove a single queuer
        queuerRemove: function(id) {
            if (id) {
                Queuers.remove(id);
            }
        },
        // reset the entire db of queuers
        queueReset: function() {
            Queuers.remove({});
        },
        messageQueuer: function(data) {
            var queuer = data.queuer;

            twilio = Twilio('KEY', 'KEY');
            twilio.sendSms({
                to: '+1' + queuer.phoneNumber, // Any number Twilio can deliver to
                from: '+NUMBER', // A number you bought from Twilio and can use for outbound communication
                body: data.message // body of the SMS message
            }, function(err, responseData) { //this function is executed when a response is received from Twilio
                if (!err) { // "err" is an error received during the request, if any
                    // "responseData" is a JavaScript object containing data received from Twilio.
                    // A sample response from sending an SMS message is here (click "JSON" to see how the data appears in JavaScript):
                    // http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#example-1
                    console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+NUMBER"
                    console.log(responseData.body); // outputs "word to your mother."
                }
            });

            return {
                date: queuer.date
            };           
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No repro on my side with your code. I assume you have defined this method again in another file.

Comment: Try `diff`ing the old, broken folder with the new-heroku-cloned folder.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have `ddp` in your `packages` folder, i guess you import the `autoform` or one of the project twice

try remove the `packages` folder and try again

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I dont use autoform, and wont deleting the packages folder ruin my entire meteor development enviroment? Sounds a little sketchy.